# How to POST an array in Rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to POST a data as JSON to the controller

in javascript, the data is an array, for example, a = [1,2]

then I POST, say

```
$.post('user/data', {'data' : a})
```

in the user controller, I get the data from params.

However, when I retrieve params[:data], I got a hash:

```
{"0"=>1, "1"=>2}
```

rather then an array!

so I have to convert the hash into an array manually.

Is there a method to pass the exact array to the controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410810/rails-not-decoding-json-from-jquery-correctly-array-becoming-a-hash-with-intege

Comment: what if to use `a.map(&:id)` if a is the collection of objects?

Comment: @kishie:yeah..but it's still manually..

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem recently.  My fix was to send json content instead of the default form encoded.

I used

```
 $.ajax(
 {
   type: "POST", 
   url: url, 
   data: JSON.stringify(data), 
   dataType: "json", 
   contentType: 'application/json'
 }
 );
```

In your example this could be done as:

```
$.ajax(
       {
         type: "POST", 
         url: 'user/data', 
         data: JSON.stringify({'data' : a}), 
         dataType: "json", 
         contentType: 'application/json'
       }
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to convert the JSON to a string, but this would work:

`/path/to/url?data[]=1&data[]=2&data[]=3`

And in the controller, do something like:

```
params[:data].each_with_index do |data, index| 
   do_something_with_data
end
```