# In Ajax request in JSON to controller, indices are added to list of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

We send some data to a Rails controller:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/haha',
  type: 'put',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    multiplication: 
    [
      {
        "a": 5,
        "b": 5
      },
      {
        "a": 5,
        "b": 5
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

The controller receives it. In the parameters, indices miraculously appear for each hash in the list:

```
# after converting to Ruby 
{ 
  "multiplication"=> {
    "0"=> { # WHAT?!
      "a"=>"5",
      "b"=>"5"
    },
    "1"=> { # BAM!
      "a"=>"5",
      "b"=>"5"
    },
  }
}
```

Is this working as intended? Can we prevent it from adding the index?

Comment: We had this problem a while back - the indexing is caused by how Rails handles JSON requests. Because you're creating an array (with `[]`), Rails is just adding indexes to the hash. I can dig out a fix if you let us know what you're trying to achieve. The problem is that JSON is made up of `name/value` pairs, and Rails tries to create these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  type : "put",
  url :  'http://localhost:3000/haha',
  dataType: "json",
  contentType : "application/json",
  dataType: 'json',
  data : {multiplication:  JSON.stringify( [{"a": 5,"b": 5},{  "a": 5,  "b": 5}])} 
});
</script>
```

[More info here in this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410810/rails-not-decoding-json-from-jquery-correctly-array-becoming-a-hash-with-intege)