# Saving attribute from array of objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm passing as array of JSON object as a param in Rails through an AJAX post/delete, like

```
[{'id': 3, 'status': true}, {'id': 1, 'status': true}]
```

How do I loop through the `params[:list]` to get each id and status value?

Comment: In params... it becomes ["0", {"id"=>"9", "status"=>"true"}]

Comment: Error: can't convert Symbol into Integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two steps to this, plus what @Agis suggested. (Thanks @Agis)

I had to first stringify the JSON:

```
'p': JSON.stringify(p),
```

So that it does not create that wierd array. There was another stackoverflow answer using this method to generate a correct data JSON object, but it was encapsulating the whole data... I need to have this on just `p` and not affect 'stringifying' the security token.
Understood this from here: [Rails not decoding JSON from jQuery correctly (array becoming a hash with integer keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410810/rails-not-decoding-json-from-jquery-correctly-array-becoming-a-hash-with-intege)

Next, I had to decode just that param, using

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:p])
```

a clue from here: [How do I parse JSON with Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails)

Lastly, can I then use the loop and access `item['id']`

Answer (score 0):

Try like follows:

```
params[ :list ][ 0 ][ :id ] # => 3, ...
params[ :list ].each {| v | v[ :id ] } # => 3, 1
```

In case if your hash is like `["0", {"id"=>"9", "status"=>"true"}]`:

```
# a = ["0", {"id"=>"9", "status"=>"true"}]
h = Hash[[a]]
# => {"0"=>{"id"=>"9", "status"=>"true"}}
```

and access to it will be:

```
h['0'][ :id ] # => '9'
```

Comment: @bcm dump the `params[ :list ][ 0 ].inspect`

Comment: Thanks, I've posted the answer which deals with the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
params[:list].each do |hash|
  hash['id'] # => 3
  hash['status'] # => true
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this loop through each item? I.E you don't need to loop through the `hash` variable?

Comment: Thanks, this is correct, the answer I've posted has this and also deals with the issue why this couldn't work beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a loop:

```
params[:list].each do |item|
    item.id
    item.satus
end
```

If you want to create an array of `id`'s or something:

```
list_ids = params[:list].map(&:id)
```