# Input array is converted to hash in Rails params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

I am sending an array in AJAX request:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.0.15/calc",
        data: {
            "phone": phone,
            "points": [
                { "lat": 59.15234, "lon": 30.99 },
                { "lat": 59.15244, "lon": 30.99 },
                { "lat": 59.15254, "lon": 30.99 }
            ],
            "start_at": 1407249093,
            "certificate": "849840487484"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(jqXHR.statusCode());
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    }
);
```

Then inspect points:

```
params[:points].inspect
```

and see a hash:

```
{
  "0"=>{"lat"=>"59.15234", "lon"=>"30.99"},
  "1"=>{"lat"=>"59.15244", "lon"=>"30.99"},
  "2"=>{"lat"=>"59.15254", "lon"=>"30.99"}
}
```

How to get an array instead of hash (preferably initially, without having to convert the hash to array)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails not decoding JSON from jQuery correctly (array becoming a hash with integer keys)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410810/rails-not-decoding-json-from-jquery-correctly-array-becoming-a-hash-with-intege)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution here

[Rails not decoding JSON from jQuery correctly (array becoming a hash with integer keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410810/rails-not-decoding-json-from-jquery-correctly-array-becoming-a-hash-with-intege)

simply you need to add the content type and set it to  `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: Unfortunately the solution pointed out there causes the jQ to send an OPTIONS request. I didn't even know that this HTTP method exists. Response is 404.

Comment: P.S. It was because of same domain policy. After putting the ths form into web application everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can then do:

```
"points": [
    '{ "lat": 59.15234, "lon": 30.99 }',
    '{ "lat": 59.15244, "lon": 30.99 }',
    '{ "lat": 59.15254, "lon": 30.99 }'
]
```

Now this will be considered as array of strings and when parsing you can convert it to hash to parse.

Tell me if this solves your issue.

**EDIT**

```
$.ajax({
  ..
  ..
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data : JSON.stringify({"points": [
     { "lat": 59.15234, "lon": 30.99 },
     { "lat": 59.15244, "lon": 30.99 },
     { "lat": 59.15254, "lon": 30.99 }]
  })
});
```

Comment: This seems to look like a workaround rather than real solution.