# Parsing JSON with jQuery turns array into hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a string like this:

```
string = '{ "key": [
  { "foo": "bar" }
] }';
```

This string is converted into a JSON object by doing

```
json = $.parseJSON(string);
```

and then it looks like this:

```
{ "key":
  { "0":
    { "foo": "bar" }
  }
}
```

So it seems like the array was converted into a hash.

The desired outcome would instead be:

```
{ "key": [
  { "foo": "bar" }
] }
```

What's the best way to achieve this? Background: I am posting JSON data to a URL but need the array to stay intact so the recipient can parse it accordingly.

**Update**

Here is what I see in a console of Chrome 37.0.2062.120 and jQuery 1.11.1:

[image]

It looks like an array, but is really just another hash with a key of "0". Or am I getting something wrong?

**Update 2**

After converting the string into a JSON update I am posting it to a url:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://test.com',
    data: json,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'post'
  })
```

where it arrives as

```
{ "key":
  { "0":
    { "foo": "bar" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your string isn't valid Json. I get "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :*". If you start with a valid Json string like `'{"key": [{ "foo": "bar" }]}'`, you'll get the expected result.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. Updated my question.

Comment: Sorry, but I still can reproduce the behavior. When I parse that string, I get exactly the desired output. Are you sure it's not just an issue with how you're displaying the result?

Comment: Yes, where are you "seeing" this output?

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot from my console.

Comment: In Javascript, everything is a hash of key and value which is  why you see hash for Arrays with index as hash key and value as object.

Comment: Arrays are objects and each element is a property of that object. You can tell that `key` is an array because its prototype is `Array.prototype` (also it has a `length` property, so it certainly does not look like `{ "0": { "foo": "bar" } }`).

Comment: Your screenshot shows you that it is indeed an array, you're just confused by the keys. Try to do `JSON.stringify($.parseJSON(string))` Remember that Array extends Objects so they look like objects too, with additional properties like length, forEach, push...

Comment: @JuanMendes That looks promising. The issue is that I am posting the JSON object to a URL and it arrives there as `{ "key": { "0": {...} } }` as opposed to `{ "key": [...] }`. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: @Charles Where is the code that is doing the encoding? You should post that

Comment: @Charles is `string` the same variable as `string = '{ "key": [
  { "foo": "bar" }
] }';` ? You should show more context. Where is string coming from?

Comment: @JuanMendes Sorry, I am posting `json` of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61308/discussion-between-juan-mendes-and-charles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send the AJAX, you can encode the JSON yourself

For JSONP, use

```
var json = '{ "key": [  { "foo": "bar" }] }';
var jsObj = $.parseJSON(json);
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://test.com',
    // You have to convert your JS object into a JSON string on your own
    // jQuery will convert them into form encoded values if you leave it as an object
    // But you want to send your whole JSON as one of the keys, 
    // so do use an object around your json to specify the the name of the
    // key value pair containing the JSON
    data: {myKey: JSON.stringify(jsObj)},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    // The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410810/rails-not-decoding-json-from-jquery-correctly-array-becoming-a-hash-with-intege
   // suggests you may need this for Rails to understand it
    contentType: 'application/json'
    // type can't be post for JSONP
    // type: 'post'
  })
```

For a POST, use

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/my/url/',
    // For POST, you can post the entire string, converting it on your own
    data: JSON.stringify(jsObj),
    type: 'POST'
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, everything is a hash of key and value which is  why you see hash for Arrays with index as hash key and value as object.

This works for me.

```
var jsonStr = '{ "key": [{ "foo": "bar" }] }';

var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonStr);
if (obj.key instanceof Array) {
alert('value is Array! and its length is > '+obj.key.length);
} else {
alert('Not an array');
}
```

http://jsbin.com/rifinu/1/

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, that all needs to be wrapped up in braces like so

```
string = '{"key": [
  { "foo": "bar" }
]}';
```

Which is going to let jQuery parse it with `jQuery.parseJSON(string)`

It's wrapped up in an array, which is why you're getting an array. I'm guessing here, but is what you really want:

```
string = '{"key": 
  { "foo": "bar" }
}';
```

so that you can access "bar" by just hitting `array['key']['foo']`? If so, remove those brackets.