# Permitting a nested arrays with strong parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

here is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/menu_items",
method: "post",
data: {
    menu_items: [
        {"id":3,"content":"first"},
        {"id":4,"content":"first"},
        {"id":5,"content":"second"}
    ]
  }
})
```

I want to permit `id` and `content` in the menu_items array,
and I read the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit).

so I try

`params.require(:menu_items).permit({menu_items: [[:id, :content]]})`

or

`params.require(:menu_items).permit({menu_items: [:id, :content]})`

but doesn't work, so what should I do?

update: here is my controller:

```
class MenuItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    puts "----------------"
    puts menu_items_param
    puts "-----------"
  end

  private
  def menu_items_param
    params.require(:menu_items).permit(menu_items: [:id, :content])
  end
end
```

In console, it print

```
Processing by MenuItemsController#create as */*
 Parameters: {"menu_items"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"3", "content"=>"first"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"4", "content"=>"first"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"5", "content"=>"second"}}}
----------------
Unpermitted parameters: 0, 1, 2
{}
-----------
```

Comment: Fix you Ajax call like this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11697679/2767755) and you will be done.

Answer (score 1):

```
params.require(:menu_items).permit(:id, :content)
```

Try this.

Comment: thanks, but doesn't work

Comment: paste your params from log

Comment: `Unpermitted parameters: 0, 1, 2`

Comment: paste params..not the warning..

Comment: @ChiangDi Paste the Application full log.

Comment: `Parameters: {"menu_items"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"3", "content"=>"first"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"4", "content"=>"first"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"5", "content"=>"second"}}}`

Comment: @ChiangDi There is the error...