# How to iterate over an array with hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

How to iterate over an array with hash that has the position included? Could I remove it? I've never come across this before.

```
var data = [
 {
   id: 1,
   foo: "hello",
   ...,
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   foo: "world",
   ...,
 }
]
```

When I POST this `data` to my controller, in my console I see the `data` params also includes the position (0, 1, 2, etc) so I cant iterate over it properly. The full look would be:

**React:**

```
...

$.ajax({
  url: '/the-url',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {'line_items': data, // this would have been this.state.data
          ...
        },
  success: function (data, xhr) {
      console.log("success")

  }.bind(this),
  error: function (data) {
      console.log("error")
  }
});

...
```

**Controller:**

```
...

line_items = params[:line_items]
line_items.map do |l| l.id end # error

...
```

**Console:**

```
0
{"id"=>"1", "foo"=>"hello"},
1
{"id"=>"2", "foo"=>"world"},
```

Also Rails 5 says `map` is depreciated. So what to use?

Comment: Have you tried line_items.map do |l| l[:id] end

Comment: @hcarreras Yes. `Got no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

Comment: could you try line_items.map do |l| l["id"] end

Comment: @hcarreras It's the same. The issue is that I need a way to remove the array position before I post to controller. The numbered position of the array is being submitted.

Comment: Maybe you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410810/rails-not-decoding-json-from-jquery-correctly-array-becoming-a-hash-with-intege

Comment: you try with `line_items.each` or `line_items.each_with_idex`??

Comment: @inye Does not work. I'll try the link siekfried stated.